# <p> tag drops <div> tag Inline-block IE 8

Tags: css, layout, internet-explorer-8

i have a div wich contains three children nodes

and another

in chrome all three divs appear inline and the parent divs height is 25px

in IE the div tags drop down because of the

tag below i have copy pasteable code that wil reproduce the problem for you

```
        <style>
        .left{
        float:left;
        }

        .right{
        float:right;
        }

        .grippie{
            width:2px;
            background:black;
            display:inline-block;
            z-index:200;
            height:100%;
            zoom:1;
            z-index:200;
            *display:inline;
        }

        .task P{
        width:90%;
        display:inline;
        }
        .task{
            position:absolute;
            z-index:50;
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:center;
            overflow:hiddesn;
        }

        /* task rag */
        .task.red{
            background: rgb(242,55,55); /* Old browsers */
            /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
            background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,55,55,1) 1%, rgba(255,58,58,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,rgba(242,55,55,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,58,58,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,55,55,1) 1%,rgba(255,58,58,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,55,55,1) 1%,rgba(255,58,58,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(242,55,55,1) 1%,rgba(255,58,58,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(242,55,55,1) 1%,rgba(255,58,58,1) 100%); /* W3C */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f23737', endColorstr='#ff3a3a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
        }

        .task.green{
            background: rgb(168,220,24); /* Old browsers */
            /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
            background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(168,220,24,1) 0%, rgba(143,195,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(168,220,24,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(143,195,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(168,220,24,1) 0%,rgba(143,195,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(168,220,24,1) 0%,rgba(143,195,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(168,220,24,1) 0%,rgba(143,195,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(168,220,24,1) 0%,rgba(143,195,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a8dc18', endColorstr='#8fc300',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */

        }

        .task.amber{
            background: rgb(241,218,54); /* Old browsers */
            /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
            background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(241,218,54,1) 0%, rgba(239,220,95,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(241,218,54,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(239,220,95,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(241,218,54,1) 0%,rgba(239,220,95,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(241,218,54,1) 0%,rgba(239,220,95,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(241,218,54,1) 0%,rgba(239,220,95,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(241,218,54,1) 0%,rgba(239,220,95,1) 100%); /* W3C */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f1da36', endColorstr='#efdc5f',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
        }

        </style>

<div id="AEW1T3Task" class="task amber" style="height: 25px; width: 103px; top: 101px; left: 312px;">
    <p>Style IT<p/>
    <div id="AEW1T3Taskgrippie" class="grippie right"></div>
    <div class="grippie left"></div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Here is a jsFiddle of the code above:  http://jsfiddle.net/7R2uy/

Comment: Please rewrite your question using complete sentences with some basic punctuation.  I don't fully understand what you're trying to tell us.

Comment: For one thing, your closing p tag is wrong: </p> not <p/>. In fact, I wonder if that might even be causing the problem.

Comment: nah problem was there before

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will solve your problem, place this code on the top of your html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Because of DOCTYPE div-s are rendered correctly inline with p.

To prove my point take a look [here](http://www.fajrunt.com/test/index.html).

Also take note that inline-block has some [problems](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/) with width. If possible use display: block; and float: left (right).

Comment: And why not just `<!DOCTYPE html>`?  True, if the OP forgot a `doctype`, he'd likely have IE issues.  However, without seeing his actual page, what leads you to believe this is the problem?

Comment: Simple, I tried it on my local computer and its working just fine with DOCTYPE. So this is a solution to this problem.

Comment: My point is, since he did not show us, **how do you know** he also left off his `doctype`?  Any other invalid HTML, would also cause IE to render in quirks mode.

Comment: Because from his css you can see he dont have that much experience. A lot of people don't know DOCTYPE exist. Not to mention his error only occurs without DOCTYPE.

Comment: New web pages have no use for the transitional doctype. You should always use strict.

Comment: lol well good guess i did leave out the doctype :) and didnt know abou t it